# Create a catch-all zone in an authoritative DNS server

Tags: dns, bind

I would like to have a DNS server which returns `@ CNAME example.com.` for all requests unless otherwise specified. This will be used as the authoritative server for clients who don't customize their DNS.

Is it possible to configure BIND to have one catch-all zone file for any requests which don't have their own zone file?

Comment: Yes, I think that would work. Have you tried it?

Comment: I'm not really sure what that would look like.

Comment: It would be a single root zone with a wildcard CNAME record in it!

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/a/397011/396475 and bind RPZ feature.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to add a wildcard `CNAME` record.

```
*.example.com.    IN      CNAME       example.com.
```